# How get another column value from the same row if we update any column of that row in oracle trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers

TABLE NAME : TEST

COLUMNS : ID,NAME

I am using ORACLE database.

I have written one trigger after update.

If I update name column value then I want to get ID of that updated name.

Please give me any suggestion.

Thanks....

Comment: What do you want to do with the ID of that updated name? Are you just using that elsewhere in your trigger? What does your trigger currently do (please show your code) and what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:OLD` check the below example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EX_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE ON TAB1
BEGIN
   SET VAR = :OLD.ID
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id INT, name VARCHAR2(20) );
CREATE TABLE table_name_log( prev_id INT, id INT, update_date DATE );

CREATE TRIGGER log_id
AFTER UPDATE
  ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :old.name <> :new.name THEN
    INSERT INTO table_name_log (
      prev_id, id, update_date
    ) VALUES (
      :old.id, :new.id, SYSDATE
    );
  END IF;
END;
/

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT 1, 'Alf' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Ben' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carl' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
UPDATE table_name SET name = 'Ann' WHERE id = 1;

SELECT * FROM table_name_log;
```

**Output**

```
PREV_ID ID UPDATE_DATE
------- -- -------------------
      1  1 2016-06-02 09:56:23
```